# mxGraph diagrameditor change label position

Tags: javascript, jgraph, mxgraph

I'm editing the digrameditor in [here](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/examples/editors/)! for my own project and I need to position the labels of the vertices to bottom. I tried by adding follow changes but seems it's not the case.

```
....
// Program starts here. The document.onLoad executes the
// mxApplication constructor with a given configuration.
// In the config file, the mxEditor.onInit method is
// overridden to invoke this global function as the
// last step in the editor constructor.
function onInit(editor)
{
     // Set align of the labels to bottom
     mxConstants.STYLE_VERTICAL_LABEL_POSITION = mxConstants.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
....
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found out that it can be done using the **diagrameditor.xml** file locates in the [config](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/tree/master/javascript/examples/editors/config) directory. You can find the mxStylesheet defined as **stylesheet** in line 123 and in their you can find the **defaultVertex** style. Change the **verticalAlign** attribute to **bottom** as follows.

```
...
<add as="align" value="left"/>
<add as="verticalAlign" value="bottom"/>
<add as="shadow" value="0"/>
....
```